# Static C++ variable, without default constructor, loses value

Tags: c++, sdl, static-variables

I have a class with a static variable. Since I need a constructor that isn't the default, I'm getting a little confused, but I hope I did it well

Class

```
class Object3D{

    public:
        static Object3D ObjControl;

        Object3D(); //this is here just for the initialization of the static variable

        Object3D(Triangle *mesh);

        Triangle *mesh;

};
```

At this point I need to create an Object3D and I do as below

```
bool Engine::OnInit() {

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if((Surf_Display = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGTH, BBP, FLAGS)) == NULL) {
            return false;
        }

        arma::colvec::fixed<3> upDirection;
        upDirection << 0 << 1 << 0;

        Camera cam(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0, 200.0, 90.0, upDirection);
        Camera::CameraControl = cam;

        arma::colvec::fixed<3> vertexA;
        vertexA << -1 << 1 << 0;

        arma::colvec::fixed<3> vertexB;
        vertexB << 1 << 1 << 0;

        arma::colvec::fixed<3> vertexC;
        vertexC << 0 << -1 << 0;

        Triangle tri(vertexA, vertexB, vertexC);
        Triangle mesh[1];
        mesh[0] = tri;
        Object3D obj(mesh);

        Object3D::ObjControl = obj; // PROBLEM! -> when the function extis from the OnInit ObjControl doesn't have anything inside.. it is like cleaned at the exit


        return true;
    }
```

The problem is the one that is inserted in the comment before the return.

Then when I need to pass that object to the rendering function, as below; the application closes because I'm trying to access to a location of memory not initialized

```
void Engine::OnRender(){

    Rendering.WfRender(Object3D::ObjControl, Surf_Display, 1);

}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the static variable, but I did the same with a static variable for a Camera class, as you can see in the Engine::OnInit, and there everything works well. So I have no clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Does your `Object3D` class only hold onto the pointer to the mesh or take a copy of it?
- Does it implement a deep-copy copy constructor?

I ask because your `mesh` is going out of scope after being assigned to `obj`, and `obj` is going out of scope after being assigned to the static variable.  You need to either assign the mesh on the heap and hand that pointer to the static variable, or ensure the actual data is copied by correctly implementing the right constructors.

EDIT: Or, as this looks like games development, get it done quick and nasty!  ;-)

```
Object3D::ObjControl.mesh = new Triangle(vertexA, vertexB, vertexC);
```

...and lose the local variables `tri`, `mesh`, and `obj`.

Comment: Yes yes, it is. I'm coding wireframe rendering as assignment. Thank you for the last suggestion. Anyway yes, I have to focus a bit more on the dynamic allocation memory and the scope stuff

Comment: Ok I have fixed it. I wasn't realizing something about the static variables. I was initializing it but not using in the way it is supposed to. Anyway now it is fine. Thank you for the hard work! 
Always pleased to post here! :)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue in your program is that you make a Triangle instance (mesh) in your function and that you pass a pointer to your static member variable ObjControl.  When you leave the function, mesh is no longer available, so ObjControl points to an invalid instance.  This could be solved by storing an actual Triangle instead of a pointer to a Triangle in Object3D or a container of Triangles if more are needed.

Comment: I need to try this, but what you're saying should be my problem. I'll let you know as soon as possible!